# Keep method running when app is terminated

Tags: flutter, dart

Most of mobile apps should be able to keep some methods running even if app is killed. In our case we have a setup process which is going to take about 40-50 seconds, it will start when user launched the app for first time. Or in another case, users can download some data, they will start to download it in app but app should finish downloading even if app is not in foreground. So, the method starts to run when app is on foreground, not in background. But we need at keep it running even if user terminated the app.

I've tried [**workmanager**](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager), [**flutter_background_service**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) and [**background_fetch**](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch). None of these packages provides this. Do you have any advices?